# Include string variables in subprocess.check_output

Tags: python

I am trying to execute following command:

```
result = subprocess.check_output("curl -o '/Users/user/Desktop/workbook.twb' -u xxx:yyy https://bitbucket.xyz.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/xxx/repos/xxx/raw/yyy/test_folder/test.twb", shell=True)
```

In the above command, I need to replace /Users/user/Desktop/workbook.twb with a string variable e.g. filePath and https://bitbucket.xyz.com/rest/api/1.0/projects/xxx/repos/xxx/raw/yyy/test_folder/test.twb with another variable e.g. repo_path..How can I achieve this?

I tried multiple ways but getting formatting errors in all of them.

Comment: Why bother with running a curl command? I mean you can. But you might as well just use requests module... code will be cleaner in my opinion and it will also work on machines that don't have curl installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like that:

```py
param_a = "foo"
param_b = "bar"

query_url = "http://some.host/{a}/{b}.xml".format(a=param_a, b=param_b)
print(query_url)  # To understand what's happening.

command = "curl -o '{output_file}' '{query_url}'".format(
  output_file="/Users/me/foo-bar",
  query_url=query_url
)
print(command)

result = subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
```

Make every step small. When in doubt, print intermediate values.

Comment: Not using `shell=True` avoids the need to shell escape the arguments: `result = subprocess.check_output(["curl", "-o", output_file, query_url])`.

Comment: This worked like a charm..I was missing the logic to form command as mentioned..thanks a lot